# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in spite of the conditionals

Tags: javascript, facebook, parsing, sdk, undefined

I'm trying to retrieve images on Facebook Parse SDK, and I can't because of this error. And I don't know what i'm doing wrong because I use a conditional in order to no not to create a new variable if this is empty or undefined. This is the code (the console log points the error in the line where i'm creating the var ImageFl):

```
var Encharcamientos1 = Parse.Object.extend("Report");
var query = new Parse.Query(Inundaciones1);
query.equalTo("Tipo_Reporte", "Encharcamientos");
query.find({


success: function(results) {
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values

for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
if (!object.get('ImageFile') || object.get('ImageFile') !== '' || typeof object.get('ImageFile') !== 'undefined') {
var imageFl = object.get('ImageFile');
var imageURL = imageFl.url();
$('.imagen')[0].src = imageURL;
}

    var object = results[i];
     L.marker([object.get('Latitud'),object.get('Longitud') ], {icon: EncharcamientosIcon}).bindPopup(' <p><span class="grande"> ' + object.get('Tipo_Reporte') + ' </span></p><p>Fecha: ' + object.get('Fecha') + ' </p><p>Hora: ' + object.get('Hora') + '<div class="imagen"></div>' + '</p><p>Comentarios:<br /> ' + noundefined(object.get('Comentario')) + '</p>').addTo(Encharcamientos).addTo(todos);
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is probably that the variable `object` is `undefined`. Where does it get set? You did not post enough code.

Comment: Well why do you expect `object` to have any particular value? Clearly, it does not, and that is what the error means.

Comment: Edit that code into your question instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: OK, so look at your code - you're defining the variable `object` **after** that initial `if` statement in the loop. Code is evaluated from top to bottom.

Comment: In this loop i getting the information from the database, and so, object(blabla) not always have information, so I have to use a conditional to avoid declaring ImageFl when "object.get('ImageFile') don't have information.

Comment: Right, but what happens on the very first time through the loop? The variable `object` is not assigned a value until **after** that code looks at it. Why do you have `var object = results[i];` after the start of the loop body?

Comment: You are right, I putted "var object = results[i]; above, but now I have this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: That means `object.get("ImageFile")` is returning `undefined`. In general, "Cannot read property "something" of undefined" means you've got a variable on the left side of a `.` that has no value (is `undefined`).

Comment: Yes, but if his declaraton is conditioned by an if, so why is still returning the error? I wan't to declare the variables only when object.get("ImageFile") has information.

Comment: `undefined` is not equal to `''`. Your `if` statement will proceed if `object` is truthy, if it's not equal to `''`, or it's type is not `undefined`.  Since it is not equal to `''`, the code in the `if` statement is evaluated.

Comment: I took out that and i still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

The object wasn't being set before the if statement. *update, added code from comments*

```
var Encharcamientos1 = Parse.Object.extend("Report");
var query = new Parse.Query(Inundaciones1);
query.equalTo("Tipo_Reporte", "Encharcamientos");

query.find({

    success: function(results) {
        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i]; // <-- THIS NEEDS TO BE BEFORE IF STATEMENT

            var imageFl = object.get('ImageFile');
            alert(imageFl);

            if (imageFl !== '' && typeof imageFl !== 'undefined') {
                var imageURL = imageFl.url();
                $('.imagen')[0].src = imageURL;
            }

            L.marker([object.get('Latitud'),object.get('Longitud') ], {icon: EncharcamientosIcon}).bindPopup(' <p><span class="grande"> ' + object.get('Tipo_Reporte') + ' </span></p><p>Fecha: ' + object.get('Fecha') + ' </p><p>Hora: ' + object.get('Hora') + '<div class="imagen"></div>' + '</p><p>Comentarios:<br /> ' + noundefined(object.get('Comentario')) + '</p>').addTo(Encharcamientos).addTo(todos);
        }
    },

    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but the console shows now this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: The part of the condition **!object.get('ImageFile')** is saying to run when no ImageFile is found.  You should remove that part of the condition.

Comment: You'll need take a look at the returned value.  Try setting a var before the if and alerting the value.  **var imgageFl = object.get('ImageFile')** then **alert(imageFl)** and change the if to **if(imageFl !== '' && typeof imageFl !== 'undefined')**.

Comment: Also notice the **&&** in my last post.  The if condition with the OR was essentially saying "if imageFl isn't empty OR imageFl isn't 'undefined'" so what was happening is it was saying "okay the imageFl is 'undefined' and that's not empty so go ahead"

Comment: I am curious to see what was returned.  We're doing some strict comparisons and maybe those needed to be loosened up. Basically only continue if it's NOT false, null, undefined, or empty.  Post whatever you find as it could help someone else.

Comment: With the alert, the first value is "undefined", and the second is "[object][object]". Now i put the variable declaration inside the loop (to avoid the "undefined" variables). The mistake in the console log disappeared but nothing happens (if i make an "alert" or use the console.log() function nothing appears).